# What are disadvantages in disabling reactor-netty connection pool?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

Recently in our application we are facing the below error quite frequently.

**Error :**

> reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
>       at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:356) ~[reactor-core-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
>   ... 55 lines omitted ...
>           ... 52 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE 
>   response

When I searched online for this error, it was [reported](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22464) as a bug in reactor-netty  and some suggested to disable reactor-netty client connection pool to prevent this error as a workaround.

So I just wanted to understand what will be the disadvantages to disable the connection pool??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the link referring to this as a bug?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22464

Comment: Can you please post what versions of webflux, reactor-core, reactory netty is beeing used.

Comment: I am using spring-boot-starter-webflux. It already comes with reactor-netty in it.           
spring-boot-starter-webflux version : 2.2.3-RELEASE                                                    reactor-netty version : 0.8.14-RELEASE

Comment: I would encourage you to try to understand why this happens instead of disabling the pool. It can be a bug in Reactor Netty, but also it can be a misconfiguration in your application. This may happen if you have a TCP keepalive timeout setting, which you can resolve configuring maxLifeTime for your pool, or you may have proxy/server with max idle timeout setting, which you can resolve configuring maxIdleTime for you pool etc. Take a tcp dump and check which peer closes the connection.

Comment: ok, i will check the configuration on application side and see whether that works or not. Thanks

Comment: I am configuring my connection pool like this (I don't see a handler to configure maxLifeTime)  -  HttpClient.create().tcpConfiguration(client ->
                client.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 60000)
                        .doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(60)))
                        .doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(60))));

Comment: you should use `HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider........)`. The ConnectionProvider configures your connection pool.